# Maven LCOVSensor analysing, but not showing up in Sonar

Tags: code-coverage, sonarqube, lcov

This is part of my `mvn sonar:sonar`

```
[INFO] [16:26:15.969] Sensor LCOVSensor...
[INFO] [16:26:15.971] Analysing D:\app\willem\target\lco
v.info
[INFO] [16:42:49.902] Sensor LCOVSensor done: 6 ms
```

So that lcov.info is processed, and that lcov.info is correctly filled with stuff like

```
TN:
SF:D:/app/willem/components/main/controller.js
FN:24,(anonymous_1)
FNF:9
FNH:5
FNDA:4,(anonymous_1)
```

Yet Sonar shows up empty, 0% coverage, no files included etc. Anybody a hint?

Comment: What if you change to relative path in your LCOV report? Relative path to the source directory defined in your SonarQube configuration file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @DavidRACODON ! It turned out to be that indeed Sonar did not recognize my sources, and that was because I forgot to include a <sourceDirectory>.</sourceDirectory> tag in the POM.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer

Apparently, I forgot to include the

```
<sourceDirectory>.</sourceDirectory>
```

in the POM's `<build>` tag so it didn't know about my sources, even though it did correctly analyse the lcov.info file.

Thanks anyway!